# Adding items into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have a problem with my code for a project I am working on. I am currently trying to manipulate dictionaries and add things into them, but there is something weird going on with my code. The first step to my function is to take a text file that looks like this:

```
A;X;Y;Z
B;Y;Z;X
C;Y;Z;X
D;Z;X;Y
E;Z;X;Y
```

I then take the lines of text and put them into a dictionary. Example:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'E': {'Z', 'X', 'Y'}, 'C': {'Y', 'Z', 'X'}, 'A': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 'D': {'Z', 'X', 'Y'}, 'B': {'Y', 'Z', 'X'}})
```

I wrote the for loop to do this, but the problem I have is that when adding items to the dictionary the code mixes up the values in the dictionary for some reason.

```
def read_voter_preferences(file : open):
    votes_dict = defaultdict(set)
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split(";")
        for i in range(1,4):
            print(votes_dict)
            votes_dict[line[0]].add(line[i])
    return votes_dict
```

The output is this: `defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'E': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 'C': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 'A': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 'D': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, 'B': {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}})`

When the code adds items into a dictionary, it mixes up the order of the items of the dictionary which is important for this particular project. How do I fix this? Does .add() automatically sort the items in the list? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set`, like a `dict`, does **not** preserve order.  If the order, as you say, is important, you must therefore use a `list`, **not** a `set`, to maintain it.  So, if you're not worries about duplicates:

```
votes_dict = dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(";")
    votes_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
return votes_dict
```

Note that you don't really need a `default_dict` here.

If you need to **both** maintain order **and** remove duplicates, your life is harder, but still not too terrible; e.g:

```
votes_dict = dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(";")
    votes_dict[line[0]] = thelist = []
    seen = set()
    for item in line[1:]:
        if item in seen: continue
        thelist.append(item)
        seen.add(item)
return votes_dict
```

You *could* cut corners, avoid creating and maintaining `seen`, and use something like:

```
votes_dict = dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(";")
    votes_dict[line[0]] = thelist = []
    for item in line[1:]:
        if item in thelist: continue
        thelist.append(item)
return votes_dict
```

Checking `in` with a list rather than a set is bad in general, but fine for a very short list as you have here, so this one may be best.  (Giving a local name as an alias to the list you're building is a technique worth remembering -- no reason to **repeatedly** index `votes_dict`:-).

Comment: I did not know that about sets. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3593892, `set`s, like `dict`s, are hash tables, for efficiency, therefore order of insertion cannot be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
{'Z', 'X', 'Y'}
```

declares a *set* of items, where only membership is important, not order. So Python feels free to reorder the items when it displays the set.

To preserve the order, use a *list*:

```
['Z', 'X', 'Y']
```

Comment: I did not know that about sets. Thank you so much!